# js click onpage load based on referrer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need js clicked when page load based on referrer. 
When user came from a fixed domain name, form will auto clicked. else nothing.

Example: I need when user came from www.example.com or example.com or example.com/anypage/ in mysite.com/userinfo/ ... Form will automatically submitted. If not came from example.com .. nothing happned.

When I use without referrer code for au submit.. Its works and click .. click.. click.. on every load...and continuously clicked...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("sendit").submit();
</script>
```

Then I try to use referrer code... after add referrer code.. Its not work again.. What can I do??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer == ("http://aweber.com" || "http://www.aweber.com")) {
      document.getElementById("sendit").submit();
}
</script>
```

I also use this method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() { 
  if (document.referrer == "www.aweber.com") {
    $("#sendit").submit(); 
 } else { /* Nothing */ }
}); 
</script>
```

Any idea???

Comment: Going one step behind, why do you need a form to be submitted when someone enters the page? You could skip that step and save the data serverside when the user views the page.

Comment: `document.referrer == ("http://aweber.com" || "http://www.aweber.com")` is not what you think it is. Learn about the [Or Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
if (document.referrer == ("http://aweber.com" || "http://www.aweber.com")) {
```

You are attempting to using a javascript assignment technique instead of actually comparing the result of document.referrer.

Your statement should be:

```
if ((document.referrer == "http://aweber.com") || (document.referrer == "http://www.aweber.com")) {
```

Comment: What do you mean you prevent to re-submit? Is the submit not working now?